# [API][PHP][SMS] В доступе отказано. Не верный API передаётся в функцию

Tags: php, api, sms

При отправке тестового сообщение выдаёт ошибку "+3712995****: {"error":"access denied"}" . API ключ введён корректно.

```
return file_get_contents_curl("https://app.sms.by/api/v1/sendQuickSMS?token=".$settings["sms_service_id"]."&message=".urlencode($text)."&phone=".$phone_to);

...

function sms($phone_to="",$text=""){
   global $settings, $config;

   if($settings["sms_service_pass"]){
      $settings["sms_service_pass"] = decrypt($settings["sms_service_pass"]);
   }

   if($settings["sms_service_id"]){
      $settings["sms_service_id"] = decrypt($settings["sms_service_id"]);
   }
```

Вводя echo sms_service_id вместо API ключа появляются различные символы, не понимаю, откуда они берутся... Вот, что выводится: KX7qVDmaN9vRbnHCDmnI6N61qVJh7u7Sf2I7qHpOVUoncbgURYSfvYTMUHB047np6kO5ZjfI8dw2A1E15JLbRdV48
. Хотя сам API ключ состоит из гараздно меньших символов: fe724bs70c1e1924dae5beaa3g69e1ed.

Пробовал убрать decrypt - не помогает. Как это можно исправить?

Comment: А откуда нам знать что где и как у Вас выводится? И, уж тем более, ваше api?

Comment: Суть не в моём API, а в работе функции sms_service_id. Функцию написал, почему на Ваш взгляд, выводится не то, что я указываю, а KX7qVDmaN9vRbnHCDmnI6N61qVJh7u7Sf2I7qHpOVUoncbgURYSfvYTMUHB047np6kO5ZjfI8dw2A1?

Comment: Покажите как вы сеттерите $settings

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, как я это могу сделать? Заранее благодарю!

Comment: Возможно это то, о чём Вы говорите, InDevX:
`function settings(){
       global $config;

       $get = getAll("select * from uni_settings");
       if(count($get)){        
          foreach ($get as $key => $value) {
              $settings[$value["name"]] = $value["value"];
          }
       }`

Comment: Как можно узнать, что передаётся в функцию file_get_contents_curl? echo / var_dump не помогают в решении вопроса

Comment: И до file_get_contents_curl у Вас параметры верные?

Comment: PHP не имеет метода file_get_contents_curl, если его используете, значит он у Вас где-то создан

Comment: Вот, как работает данная функция: `'function file_get_contents_curl($url) {
 $ch = curl_init();

 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 2);

 $data = curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close($ch);

 return $data;
}`